# How to run/execute exe file in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I still new with python. I try to run an

> exe

file by using python. Can i know what should i use and import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['C:\\Temp\\a b c\\Notepad.exe', 'C:\\test.txt'])
```

---

```
import os

os.system(r'"C:/Documents and Settings/flow_model/flow.exe"')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
os.system("path_to_exe")
```

Try using this it will work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([r"path\filename.exe"]
```